# Criteria of convergence for gaussian integral with complex parameters

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

Consider the following Gaussian integral:

\begin{equation}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\mathrm{i}ax^2+bx}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Where $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $b=0$ then:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i a x^{2}} d x=e^{i \pi \operatorname{sgn}(a) / 4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4|a|}}$$
If $b$ is purely imaginary then (from wikipedia):
$$I=\left(\frac{ \pi i}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{-i \mathrm{Im}[b]^{2}}{4a}}$$

My questions:

- **If $b\in \mathbb{C}$ where $\mathrm{Re}[b]\neq 0$ what are the constraints needed on $a$ so that the integral still converges?**
- For general $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ How must $a$ relate to $b$ so that the integral converges? More generally, what are the **general** conditions for $I$ to converge? (Setting $\mathrm{Re}[a]<0$ is not the most general condition: indeed if $b=0$ and $a$ purely imaginary then $I$ still converges).

Any reference or link to a specific book/article is always appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For real $c $ and $d$ $e^{cx^{2}+dx}$ is integrable iff $c <0$. Since $|e^{ia x^{2}+bx}|=e^{\Re (ia x^{2}+bx)}=e^{-\Im a x^{2}+\Re b x}$ it folows that the required condition  is $\Im a >0$.

The integral converges for all complex $b$ if the imaginary part of $a$ is positive and diverges for all complex $b$ if the imaginary part of $a$ is non-negative.

Comment: Thank you. My question is regarding the case for non real $b$. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Matt I did not take $b$ to be real in my answer. The integral converges for all complex $b$ if the imaginary part of $a$ is positive and diverges for all complex $b$ if the imaginary part of $a$ is non-negative.

Comment: I am sorry I need to pay more attention when I read.

Comment: So I integrated numerically $I$ and when $b=0$ the sign of $\Im{a}$ does not matter. However when $\Re{b}\neq 0$ and $a$ purely imaginary my integral always diverges. This seems to be in contradiction with your answer.

Comment: @Matt. Could you provide one case  ? (the answer is perfectly correct)

Comment: For $a=1$, $b=\mathrm{i}$, $I$ converges but when $b=-\mathrm{i}$ $I$ diverges?

Comment: I agree with the second part of the answer: "$I$ diverges for all complex $b$ if the imaginary part of $a$ is non-negative". However the first part requires $\Im(a)>0$ but with my example $Im(a)=0$ and it seems that there is a condition between $a$ and $b$ and not just $Im(a)$.